# Is Arrow Streaming end-to-end copy-free

Tags: apache-arrow

I am confused about Arrow Streaming. Many sources describing Arrow just paraphrase the  [following](https://arrow.apache.org/)

> The Arrow memory format supports zero-copy reads

and say that Arrow is zero-copy tool.

However, as far as I understand [these paragraphs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#recordbatch-message):

> The primitive unit of serialized data in the columnar format is the “record batch”. Semantically, a record batch is an ordered collection of arrays, known as its fields, each having the same length as one another but potentially different data types. A record batch’s field names and types collectively form the batch’s schema.
>
> In this section we define a protocol for serializing record batches into a stream of binary payloads and reconstructing record batches from these payloads without need for memory copying.

the description of the [IPC Streaming Format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#ipc-streaming-format) and, my limited understanding, the source, data is serialized, and only deserialization is zero-copy.

In other words - systems that use Arrow Streaming actually copy the data on the way.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, Arrow is always zero-copy on the receiver side.

> systems that use Arrow Streaming actually copy the data on the way.

It depends what you mean by "copy". Is data duplicated in-memory in the same process? No. The bytes have to be transported somehow from one virtual address space to another, whether you believe that technically constitutes a "copy" or not depends on your application (and point of view, perhaps).

Here is the actual C++ code (as of this writing) where the data written by the sender into an `OutputStream` which is a proxy for the receiver

```cpp
  // Now write the buffers
  for (size_t i = 0; i < payload.body_buffers.size(); ++i) {
    const std::shared_ptr<Buffer>& buffer = payload.body_buffers[i];
    int64_t size = 0;
    int64_t padding = 0;

    // The buffer might be null if we are handling zero row lengths.
    if (buffer) {
      size = buffer->size();
      padding = BitUtil::RoundUpToMultipleOf8(size) - size;
    }

    if (size > 0) {
      RETURN_NOT_OK(dst->Write(buffer));
    }

    if (padding > 0) {
      RETURN_NOT_OK(dst->Write(kPaddingBytes, padding));
    }
  }
```

Nothing is being forcibly copied here. If `dst` is standing in front of a socket-like interface then the bytes go on the wire to the receiver immediately (or with buffering, or whatever the `OutputStream` is doing). If `dst` is a file handle then the bytes are written to the file, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's very helpful. So I am not insane there is copy on write, and no copy on read, right?